# Functions inside singleton?

Tags: objective-c, singleton, avaudiorecorder

How do I put a function into the singleton? i.e. so that when I use a button in another view controller, it calls the function from the singleton object file?

My current code is this:

```
    + (RecorderData *)sharedAudioRecorder
{
    static dispatch_once_t pred;
    static RecorderData *sharedInstance = nil;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^
    {
        sharedInstance = [[RecorderData alloc] init];

    });
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

Comment: You add instance methods just like you would to any class. It's no different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add functions to your file and make sure you're always using `sharedInstance` (by calling the class method you've posted) rather than instantiating multiple instances of your class. To elaborate, your singleton object file might have an instance method like this:

```
- (void) someInstanceMethod
{
    // code here
}
```

...which you could then call on the singleton like so:

```
[[RecorderData sharedInstance] someInstanceMethod];
```

Comment: on the implementation, how do I synthesise the function?

Comment: @Klaus Please take a look at my edit. Hopefully this explains your question.

Comment: is the "[[RecorderData sharedInstance] someInstanceMethod]" added into the code underneath the "sharedInstance = [[RecorderData alloc] init];" part?

Comment: No, that's a sort of template for how to call an instance method on a singleton. It can be anywhere in your code (that imports `RecorderData.h`)

Comment: @Klaus, if this resolved your difficulty, please consider accepting my answer.